# saving csv according to the name of file in python automatically

Tags: python, dataframe, txt

i don't want to save the csv files manually.Is there a code that could be done automatically?First i load the file1,convert it to dataframe and do some processes that doesn't have any significant about my question.
Here's the file:

```
file1="C:/Users/ozzgu/OneDrive/Desktop/ml articles/model/datasets/RC101.txt"
rc1=pd.read_csv(file1,sep="\s+")
```

After processing,i need to save txt file just like below.

```
vehicle1.to_csv("vehicle1_KMEANS3V_RC101.txt")
```

If I load file1=RC102.txt,does it have a way to save automatically "vehicle_KMEANS3V_RC102.txt".Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the os library to extract the file name from the path, then append the text to it, and pass it to the saving function.

```
import os

filepath = "C:/Users/ozzgu/OneDrive/Desktop/ml articles/model/datasets/RC101.txt"
filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
new_filename = "vehicle1_KMEANS3V_" + filename
print(f"Old filename: {filename}")
print(f"New filename: {new_filename}")
```

Ouput:

```
Old filename: RC101.txt  
New filename: vehicle1_KMEANS3V_RC101.txt
```